# How to display the arrow symbol in Python tkMessageBox?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, character-encoding

```
info = "Hello, Welcome" + "\n" + "Please follow the instructions"
tkMessageBox.showinfo("Welcome", info)
```

What should I add to the string info to display "Up arrow symbol" in the next line of message box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Unicode string, and include a [suitable Unicode arrow character](http://unicode-table.com/en/sets/arrows-symbols/); U+2191 for example:

```
info = u"Hello, Welcome\nPlease follow the instructions \u2191"
tkMessageBox.showinfo("Welcome", info)
```